# What is the best way to create a Microsoft Teams upload bot that uploads the contents to a web service?

Tags: azure, upload, frameworks, bots, microsoft-teams

I have Azure and I want to be able to create a simple chat-bot that is programmed to do a few simple tasks for users, i.e. take in uploaded information and pass it on to another web service. What would be the best way to do this? Should I use team's built in bot-framework? I'm not sure if it can export data externally.

Would the best way be to just create a self-service web-page? I kind of want to keep it as a bot though, since they are hip and trendy.

Any tips, guidance, or knowledge would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It certainly should be possible to do this using a bot, as Teams bots can handle 9file upload and download scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-and-receive-files?tabs=dotnet). Once the bot has received the file, it can do anything that makes sense, as the bot is fully-fledged application, written in C#, node, python, or other options (those 3 are the best supported).

If you haven't build a bot before, you can start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots), which gives links to guidance on general bot development with the Microsoft Bot Framework, as well as info on Teams-specific scenarios.